# How to Update Particular TextFormFiled value Using TextEditing Controller after fetching data from API in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, onchange, textformfield

** TextEditingController gstController =
TextEditingController(
text: snapshot.data![index].gSTNo.toString());

TextFormField(
controller: gstController,
decoration: InputDecoration(
hintText: 'Enter GST No',
border: InputBorder.none,
contentPadding:
const EdgeInsets.all(14),
),
),**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add it to init State or in any `SetState`

gstController.value = TextEditingValue(text: "ANY TEXT");

Answer (score 2):

you can follow this example

```
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  TextFormField(
    controller: textEditingController,
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
    decoration: FormFields.getInputDecoration('Email Id'),
  );
```

the after api response you can set text to textformfield using TextEditingController like this

```
   setState((){
      textEditingController.text = snapshot.data![index].gSTNo.toString()
   });
```

Comment: when I Use SetState and Load application intinal value display is blank...

Comment: Any Solutions ?

Comment: you have to use setState after you get response from api

Comment: until you get response from API it will be blank