# How to Update Particular TextFormFiled value Using TextEditing Controller after fetching data from API in flutter . Any Solution?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, response, textformfield

**How to Update Particular TextFormFiled value Using TextEditing Controller after fetching data from API in flutter?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change the value inside of a textfield flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127241/how-do-you-change-the-value-inside-of-a-textfield-flutter)

Comment: this one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/72864668/18150339

Answer (score 0):

declare a text editing controller as

```
var text_controller=TextEditingController();
```

then inside textfield,

```
TextField(
  controller : text_controller,
)
```

then change the value of that particular textfield as,

```
 setState(() {
      text_controller.text='something';
    });
```